# BigQuery Transfer Service does not copy rows from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-transfer

I have created a BigQuery transfer from AWS S3 to Google BigQuery. It fails with the following error,

> No new files found matching "gs://bqdts-amazon_s3-prod-eu-w5jetqct8ohvcjih85apf7gvkbibvbkcj9o6l67/test/files"

But, the data is successfully moved from S3 to Google Cloud

> Moving data from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud complete: Moved 10
>   object(s).

I have created a table in the BigQuery dataset also

Kindly help me resolve this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue before, and only works for me when I added "*" after the Amazon S3 URI.

Example:

Before (showed the same error as yours):
s3://mybucket/path/

After (work success):
s3://mybucket/path/*

In [General issues](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer) section on Amazon S3 transfer page, shows these recomnended action:

> Confirm that the Amazon S3 URI in the transfer configuration is correct.
>
> If the transfer configuration was meant to load all files with a
>   common prefix, ensure that the Amazon S3 URI ends with a wildcard. For
>   example, to load all files in s3://my-bucket/my-folder/, the Amazon S3
>   URI in the transfer configuration must be s3://my-bucket/my-folder/*,
>   not just s3://my-bucket/my-folder/.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar error [Amazon S3 transfers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/s3-transfer) **General issues**:

> Files are transferred from Amazon S3 but not loaded into BigQuery. The
>   transfer logs may look look similar to this:
>
> Moving data from Amazon S3 to Google Cloud complete: Moved 
>   object(s). No new files found matching .
>
> Confirm that the Amazon S3 URI in the transfer configuration is
>   correct.
>
> If the transfer configuration was meant to load all files with a
>   common prefix, ensure that the Amazon S3 URI ends with a wildcard. For
>   example, to load all files in s3://my-bucket/my-folder/, the Amazon S3
>   URI in the transfer configuration must be s3://my-bucket/my-folder/*,
>   not just s3://my-bucket/my-folder/.

Should "gs://bqdts-amazon_s3-prod-eu-w5jetqct8ohvcjih85apf7gvkbibvbkcj9o6l67/test/files" be an Amazon S3 URI : **s3://**